# Display main report and subreports on different pages

Tags: crystal-reports, report

My main report and subreport need to display on different pages. The main report shows the client details and the subreport is the total summary of clients. Both reports are grouped by manager's name.

How can I display the subreport first, then the main report on the next page for a particular manager? And how can I specify the process to continue like with first the report?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click *Header* and *Add New header*. Now you will have two *headers* one as *sub-header*.
place your *sub-report* on *first header* and main on second.